# Adding selected Spinner value in a table on runtime

Tags: android, spinner

Is it possible to add selected spinner item in a table (which is generating dynamically) in textview on button click.
Generally I use this code:

```
spinner=new String[5];
spinner[0]="1";
spinner[1]="2";
spinner[2]="3";
Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner);
        spn.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but what to do when to add the selected value in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to listen to the Spinner's OnItemSelected event. And don't forget to set the layout for the drop-down items! So in order:

1. Set the Adapter like you did correctly: `spn.setAdapter(adapter);`
2. Set the drop-down item view: `spn.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`
3. Hook on the OnItemSelected event:

spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // gets called when the user selects an item
            TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
            txt.setText((String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // what to do when nothing is selected
        }
    });
```

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

After the Spinner is populated get the Selected value in Spinner by using OnItemSelectedListener.

Here is the code to get the Selected value in Spinner :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             selectedspinnervalue =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

In which selectedspinnervalue contains the selected value..

Then you add the value in Table..